# Show that there is a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset (a,b)$, $ x_n \neq c$ where $\{f'(x_n)\} \rightarrow f'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f'$ exists on $(a,b)$ and $c\in(a,b)$. Show that there is a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset (a,b)$, $ x_n \neq c$ where $\{f'(x_n)\} \rightarrow f'(c)$

Not sure how to complete proof and if I am doing it correctly.

**Pf**

Let $\{x_n\} \rightarrow a$

$f'$ continuous on $[a,x_n]$

$f'$ differentiable on $(a,x_n)$

By Mean Value Theorem, for each n, there is a $c_n$ such that

$f'(c_n) = \frac{f(x_n)-f(a)}{x_n-a}$

Comment: Why you assume that $f'$ is differentiable, or even continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x_n=c+1/n$ for $n$ large enough that $c+1/n<b.$ Now use the mean value theorem on the two points $x_n,c.$ (maybe use $y_n$ for the starting sequence above, so that $x_n$ can be the point from MVT.)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks good: Take any sequence $(y_n)_n$ in $(a,b)$ with $y_n \to c$ and $y_n \neq c$ for all $n$. Because $f$ is differentiable at $c$ we have
$$
 \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = f'(c),
$$
from which it follows that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-c} = f'(c).
$$
By the mean value theorem there exists for every $n$ some $x_n \in (a,b)$ strictly between $c$ and $y_n$ with
$$
 \frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-c} = f'(x_n).
$$
Because $x_n$ is between $c$ and $y_n$ it follows that also $x_n \to c$, and by construction we have
$$
 f'(x_n)
 = \frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-c}
 \to f'(c).
$$